# Iterate over XML node then check if has a matching json value then select the value

Tags: json, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

Apparently I have a field call **Data** which store some xml node + json inside the those node.

I can retrieve the deliveryID by using:

```
JSON_VALUE(ml.Data.value('(/row/value)[2]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),'$.transactions[0].deliveryId') deliveryID
```

However, the transactions might not always be at the second node of it,
it can be on any row.

Is there any other way I can do to iterate the node and find if it has a json transactions inside then get the deliveryID from the row?

Thanks

```
<row>
  <value id="1ae95d67-599e-4ab6-9ffd-08d4d90ab608" display-name="Cardholder_id" data-type="Int32">17</value>
  <value id="1ae95d67-599e-4ab6-9ffd-08d4d90ab608" display-name="Cardholder_id" data-type="Int32">17</value>
  <value id="eb71fd46-f0b2-401d-9775-08d4d90ab608" display-name="Card_Number">3083 2614 5022 21321</value>
  <value id="4fc261b2-f776-4fd4-8e1d-08d4d90ab608" display-name="Email_Address">jello@anc.com</value>
  <value id="c867d4e5-cc0b-4ee6-b911-08d6134132e0" display-name="BP_TRIGGERS_2.0">{"transactions":[{"BP_CommsRef":"V0001","BP_Offer_Expiry":"2018-10-01T00:00:00","deliveryId":"20320925","Job_Number":"A34F443","Send_Date":"2018-09-26T00:00:00"}]}</value>
</row>
```

Comment: btw: I hope this is not real data...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get you correctly, you want to find a `JSON` within your `<value>` elements and read the `deliverId` from there:

```
Declare @XML xml = '
<row>
  <value id="1ae95d67-599e-4ab6-9ffd-08d4d90ab608" display-name="Cardholder_id" data-type="Int32">17</value>
  <value id="1ae95d67-599e-4ab6-9ffd-08d4d90ab608" display-name="Cardholder_id" data-type="Int32">17</value>
  <value id="eb71fd46-f0b2-401d-9775-08d4d90ab608" display-name="Card_Number">3083 2614 5022 21321</value>
  <value id="4fc261b2-f776-4fd4-8e1d-08d4d90ab608" display-name="Email_Address">jello@anc.com</value>
  <value id="c867d4e5-cc0b-4ee6-b911-08d6134132e0" display-name="BP_TRIGGERS_2.0">{"transactions":[{"BP_CommsRef":"V0001","BP_Offer_Expiry":"2018-10-01T00:00:00","deliveryId":"20320925","Job_Number":"A34F443","Send_Date":"2018-09-26T00:00:00"}]}</value>
</row>';
```

--This will check for an opening `{` (you could search for an opening `{"transactions"` as well)

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(
       @XML.query(N'/row/value[substring(text()[1],1,1)="{"]/node()')
       .value(N'text()[1]','nvarchar(max)')
       ,N'$.transactions[0].deliveryId');
```

--The same approach but looking at the attribute `display-name`

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(
       @XML.query(N'/row/value[@display-name="BP_TRIGGERS_2.0"]/node()')
       .value(N'text()[1]','nvarchar(max)')
       ,N'$.transactions[0].deliveryId');
```

The idea in short: `.query()` the XML for a `<value>` below `<row>`, which fullfills the filter. Take this `node()` and read the `.value()` from there.
This is handed into `JSON_VALUE` in order to retrieve the needed `deliveryId`.

You can do the same with the attribute `id` and you can hand in the values with a declard variable (`sql:variable()`) or from a column in your result-set (`sql:column()`).